# Get UC product attributes using Views Global PHP

Tags: 7, views, theming, ubercart

I tried using below code in Views > Global PHP field.

```
<?php

$request = db_query("SELECT data FROM {uc_order_products } WHERE order_id= $row->order_id")->fetchField();
$att =  $request;

$data = unserialize($att);

if (is_array($data['attributes'])) {
  foreach ($data['attributes'] as $attribute => $option) {
    echo $attribute . ':   ' . implode(', ', (array)$option) . '<br>';
  }
}

?>
```

Adding above code I get the below error :

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Also how do I print each attribute in a different field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$request = db_query("SELECT data FROM {uc_order_products } WHERE order_id= $row->order_id");
foreach($request as $rwq){
$att =  $rwq;

$data = unserialize($att);

if (is_array($data['attributes'])) {
  foreach ($data['attributes'] as $attribute => $option) {
    echo $attribute . ':   ' . implode(', ', (array)$option) . '<br>';
  }
}
}
?>
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

If you use a variable in your request, it's preferable to use it like this : WHERE o.order_id = :oid', array(':oid' => $row->order_id).

So I guess it would be :

```
$request = db_query('SELECT o.data FROM {uc_order_products} o WHERE o.order_id= :oid', array(':oid' => $row->order_id)')->fetchField();
```

To have different fields, you can do this processus for each field, by using multiple PhP fields in your view. But to rationalize requests, I would first do that request in the "**setup code**"  and set all your data in the $static variable.